# Can I install the same copy of Windows (same product key) onto a different drive on the same computer and switch between them with the BIOS boot menu?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, installation

Right now I have two HDDs (for storage) and two SSDs (for OS) in my computer.

On the older 64 GB SSD, I have Windows 10 installed, along with a bunch of video production software and related tools taking up most of the space. There are no games on this drive, and I don't want any games to be accessible from this Windows install.

On the newer SSD I have Arch Linux, which I use for entertainment. Gaming, casual browsing and such. It's on an ext4 partition taking up the entire drive, so this space is not accessible to Windows.

I'd like to create a space on the larger of the two HDDs to install Final Fantasy XIV, which doesn't work well for me in Wine. I've tried just creating a separate user in Windows for this purpose, but unfortunately Steam doesn't care which user you're signed into Windows as.

Can I install Windows onto a different drive on the same computer *with the same product key* and switch between them, using the BIOS boot menu I currently use to switch between Windows and Linux? Or will there be an activation issue?

As a last resort, I could remove Windows from my Macbook, but I'd rather not if at all possible.

(First edit added note about product key / licensing I meant to include but forgot)

EDIT 2: My mistake, I forgot I don't have an extra Windows product key. I have a key for a Windows 7 Upgrade which doesn't work for a new installation.

EDIT 3: I thought of a simpler alternative. I installed another instance of Steam on my HDD and since that's separate from the SSD Windows is installed on (and the Steam install with only Source Filmmaker) there is now no issue with two Windows accounts having the same Steam install directory.

Comment: this line "Can I install Windows onto a different drive on the same computer and switch between them, using the BIOS boot menu I currently use to switch between Windows and Linux? ......."  is a lot clearer than your title

Comment: Well that's what happens when you write the title before you go into further detail on your issue. Not really a big deal but edited anyway

Answer (score 3):

Here's how it works. (TL;DR: yes, you can do this. If you install another windows on your third drive, all you'll have to do is make sure that your BIOS is booting from your Arch SSD and from arch make GRUB detect your new Windows installation after you install it.)

Each hard drive or ssd has a Master Boot Record, unless you're using EFI for boot management, your bios will try to load one of your hard drives or SSDs on boot (this is something you can select, so select the appropriate hard drive). On this MBR a boot manager is installed, and the boot manager's job is to select an operating system to boot.

Microsoft's boot manager is called BOOTMGR, it only supports booting windows. The most common boot manager for Linux is called GRUB, but there are other options, GRUB supports most operating systems (all the most common ones, for desktops anyhow).

The scenario right now is that you have Windows 10 on your old SSD, which means you have BOOTMGR on that SSD, and if you tell your BIOS to boot from it, it will not detect that you have linux and boot straight into Windows without asking.

On your new SSD you have arch linux, and on that MBR you have GRUB installed, GRUB will by default ask you what OS you want to boot, and it stores all OSes it has detected in a file on your /boot partition. This file can be updated by running the **grub-mkconfig** command ([check the arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Automatically_generating_using_.2Fetc.2Fgrub.d.2F40_custom_and_grub-mkconfig)). To ensure that it will detect your windows installation, you will want to install a tool called **os-prober** before running the command, which you can run as root from your arch installation.

If you install your new Windows on your third drive, BOOTMGR will be written to that drives MBR, and all you will have to do is boot into arch linux and run that grub-mkconfig command as I said before to allow grub to detect your new windows installation, and from that point on you will always be able to select between your current Windows 10 installation, Arch installation and the new Windows 10 installation. Job done.

However you may have the alternative of shrinking your Arch's ext4 partition to create space for a new NTFS partition to install the new Windows 10 on your newer SSD alongside arch (I think 60GB is the ideal size, so if your arch SSD has that much free space, this is an option), I recommend doing this with **gparted** you only need to shrink the partition though to create an unpartitioned space, the windows 10 installation will create an NTFS partition out of the unpartitioned space on its own in the installation process if you select it.

If you however use this approach, you will face the problem that Windows's BOOTMGR overwrites your GRUB in your MBR. To fix this you will have to reinstall grub with the **grub-install** command, and to do this you need to grab an arch install CD or USB, boot from it, chroot into your physical arch installation (as you probably did to install Arch) and from there run the **grub-install** command to re-install grub to your SSDs MBR, and then of course run the **grub-mkconfig** command to detect the new OS.

Comment: I just edited the question to include the most important detail, that I wanted to use the same product key. But then I realized I actually own a product key for a Windows 7 Upgrade, which doesn't work as an installation disk. So I'll have to remove Windows from my Macbook after all, and use my Windows 8 installer and product key instead. Oops.

Comment: He asked about product keys and activation though, for when it's the same computer. It's there in the original question too.

Comment: The keys are sometimes single use, sometimes they're multi-use, very rarely they're unlimited use (usually those are only bought for enterprise and schools and such)

That's all it depends on, if it's multi-use you can use it more than once and it can be used for the new installation as far as I know. If it's a store bought windows 10 it's probably multi use, 3, 5 or 10 times or something.

Comment: The bootmgr would have to do something to prevent you from doing this anyhow, I doubt it does.

Answer (score 1):

If Multiple MS Windows operating systems are instaeed on different physical druves then you can use your BIOS to determine which one gets loaded.  Selecting the hard drive to boot from in this manner reads the master boot record to know where the OS is located.

Since you have Linux installed, why not use Grub to launch the OS of choice without having to go into the bios.  In this scenario, all OSes can be on the same physical drive.

Comment: All OSes can be on the same physical drive if you have them partitioned.

Still, one wonders how an arch Linux user doesn't even know how to multi boot...

Comment: Geez. I left out an important detail. I meant to include that I have *one* product key. I know very well how to install Windows, and how to deal with separate hard drives and partitions and all that. I'm asking about a licensing issue. I'll go edit my question.

Comment: -1  the body of his post , even the original, mentioned the activation, and he was asking about that.. (and by the way, you can even multiboot multiple windows in the same partition, different directories - tested with XP, it's called a parallel installation, I haven't tried it with 7/8/10)

Comment: Don't downvote them, I edited the question.